# In Freemarker, how do I apply at the END of an element?

Tags: freemarker, smooks

I'm using smooks/freemarker to write out a CSV and I can use `applyOnElement="#document"` to write the column headers. But I also need to add a line to the end of the document, after all of my objects have been processed.

Is there a way to trigger something at the end of the `#document` object?

Answer (score 0):

So you have set applyBefore="true" on the #document element? If so, I think you'll need to apply another Freemarker template (use another config) to the #document element, but with the applyBefore="false" (i.e. the default).